# I am using an external VPN service with WireGuard on a Raspberry Pi. How can I enable access between the Raspberry Pi and my local network?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, wireguard

All computers can connect to each other via Avahi `host.local` or IP address. But as soon as I start the wireguard service / configuration on the raspberry, it becomes separated from my internal network.

My network is pretty standard, with IPs in the `192.168.1.*` range.

What do I have to do?

My configuration:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxx
Address = 10.xxxxx/32,fc00:xxxxxx/128
DNS = 193.xxxxxxx
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = xxxxx:51820
```

Comment: Is the VPN hosted within your intranet or are you using a VPN provider?

Comment: It's an external, third party provider.

Comment: Your external third-party VPN provider will be unable to communicate with an intranet address that only exists within your network.

Comment: see if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1682055/how-can-i-manually-configure-an-application-split-tunnel-in-wireguard this may be more difficult to acheive in a zero-conf/avahi network though.

Comment: I think it's your firewall rule. You seem to have misunderstood what `--dst-type LOCAL` means. (Or, while you were busy setting up the "kill switch", you forgot you need the LAN subnet to be an exception.)

Comment: Truth is, I'm not sure if the firewall rule is necessary / makes sense at all. Is it supposed to be a kill switch or what?